# How long between Singapore tourist visas?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, tourist-visas, repeat-visits

Last month my Singapore tourist visa expired, so I returned to India.

After 1 month I am planning to apply for a new Singapore visa. Is it possible to be granted a new visa that quickly? How long am I supposed to  wait to re-apply for one?

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to extend an existing visa? Or to make a fresh application?

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge (I lived in Singapore for ~8 years and moderated [an expat forum](http://forum.singaporeexpats.com/) there), **Singapore does not publish any official guidelines for repeat visits**.  However, it's a very small country with limited opportunities for tourism.  If you spent the entire length of your previous social visit pass (three months?) in Singapore and want to return as a tourist for another long period of time, Immigration's bells start ringing.  But if you spent only a few days in the country and are returning for another few days, that will most likely be perfectly fine.

You did not say *why* you want to return to Singapore, but if your interest is more than just tourism, the solution is simple at least in theory: **get an actual visa**.  Work visa if you're working, [long-term visit pass](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=376) if you're visiting friends or family, etc.

Comment: Already i am stay in India 30 days above. Now possible to re-apply the Singapore visa.

Comment: How long did you spend in Singapore?  And how long do you want to stay next time?

Comment: already stay in 2 month, now also want 2 month social visit pass.

Comment: Like jpatokal has said, the rules don't stipulate how long you must wait between visits/visa applications. However, we are warning you that you may have troubles getting the **tourism** visa and/or entering Singapore itself, due to the total length of your original stay and your requested new stay.

Comment: @lambshaanxy It depends. My wife visited Singapore for 3 times, around 3 months, same year to stay with me. It was mentioned in the visa application. They didn't even ask a single question to my wife.