# Re-Entering Singapore on a tourist visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, visa-extensions

Please adivse in below queries.

I am a Indian, my husband is working in Singapore. 
Recently I came Singapore as a Social Visit(Tourist Visa) for One Month and sponsered by Singpore PR.

Question No:1
How many days my Visa Can renewal either One month or 2 months or more.

Question No: 2
After my revewal period is completed then I have to exit from Singapore? or can i visit any near by country and re-apply Social Visit(tourist visa) to Singapore.
In this case, how many days I need to take gap for apply Visa again?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. A Singapore tourist visa can be extended by [30 days normally, or up to 89 days in special circumstances](https://extend.ica.gov.sg/extend/index.xhtml) (family ties with a Singapore PR qualify).  This can only be done **once**.
2. [There is no documented limit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47420/how-long-between-singapore-tourist-visas?rq=1); however, it is not advisable to rely on this.  Instead, apply for a Long-Term Social Visit Pass if you wish to stay with your husband for a longer period.